# Can i get TeamCity to do what web essentials does? Less files and Bundles?

Tags: less, teamcity, bundle, web-essentials

I am trying to get TeamCity to build less files and generate my bundles.

Is this possible in Team City?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is. Anything you can run from command line you can create a build step for. So, you need to find a script you can trigger from commandline (MSBuild for example, there's even a build runner for MSBuild). I would probably collect all build files as artifacts that I can later download directly from TeamCity. Something like this (all separate build steps):

1. Build everything
2. Generate css files and bundles (maybe part of step 1).
3. Generate msi file using something like WiX.
4. Collect artifacts within TeamCity.

This is a very nice setup, in my view. Probably you need to ask for more help on each step separately.

Good luck!